# Consecutive calls to fgetc in C

Tags: c, fgetc

I am working on implementing a brainfuck interpreter, and I'm struggling with the call of two consecutive `,` commands.

Here's an extract of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MEM_SIZE 30000
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 256

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *input = ",.,.";
    char bytes [MEM_SIZE] = {0};

    int pos=0;
    int i=0;

    while (input[i] != '\0'){

        switch (input[i]){
            case '.':
                printf ("%c", bytes[pos]);
                break;
            case ',':
                printf ("Enter Number:\n");
                bytes[pos] = fgetc (stdin);
                printf ("Number Entered\n");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output of the program is the following:

```
Enter Number:
3                  // This is me, manually entering the value.
Number Entered
3Enter Number:
Number Entered
```

Why isn't the second call to `fgetc` working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What makes you think the second call to `fgetc` isn't working ? The second `fgetc` reads in an `\n` (you did press `return`, right?).

Another problem, you are reading into a char. `fgetc` returns an `int`. You should check this for `EOF` before blindly using it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not advancing your `pos` counter so the next time you save data to `bytes[pos]` you overwrite the previous data.

Btw. try to change

```
printf ("Number Entered\n");
```

into

```
printf ("Number Entered: %c\n", bytes[pos]);
```

to debug the information you receive from `fgetc()`.

Comment: While not advancing the `pos` is probably a problem (nice catch), it's not the reason of the behavior the OP is complaining about.